# reverse proxy on PFsense, squid or otherwise

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy, pfsense

I've been trying to get this to work for days now and its not working. After bashing my head against the desk enough times, I've decided to man up and ask.

I'm desperately trying to set up a reverse proxy on the pfsense box itself. One because its a pretty powerful box and its not being utilized to the maximum at all and two because I don't have any spare machines to setup squid (or any other reverse proxy [capable]) server on.

So, on pfsense, everytime I set up rules (on Services>Proxy Server>General) as so:

```
acl surveillance dstdomain surveillance.myweb.local;
acl camera dstdomain camera.myweb.local;
http_access allow surveillance AND camera
```

(ad nauseum)

when I check the services, squid stops and refuses to restart until I remove them pesky acls that are supposed to make my life easier!

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I get it to work?
3. Is there another way/package I can use?

Thanks

Comment: What version of pfSense are you running? Is it the 1.2.x branch or the 2.x experiemental? Older?

Comment: PFsense 1.2.3 release.

Answer (score 1):

1) strip out the semi-colons, I don't think you need them. Or, at least I don't have any in my squid.conf (not in 2.x or 3.x), and they work :-)

2) Shouldn't

`http_access allow surveillance AND camera`

be just

`http_access allow surveillance camera`

If that does not work, is there something in the Squid error log which would tell you why the acl rules fail?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there should be semi-colons at the end of the acl lines?  Squid 2.7 doesn't seem to use them. Ex:

acl Safe_ports port 80 443 21

Comment: Yes, its written on the page that you need to separate acls with semi-colons.